# How to stop parsing xml document with SAX at any time?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I parse a big xml document with Sax, I want to stop parsing the document when some condition establish? How to do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Create a specialization of a SAXException and throw it (you don't have to create your own specialization but it means you can specifically catch it yourself and treat other SAXExceptions as actual errors).

```
public class MySAXTerminatorException extends SAXException {
    ...
}

public void startElement (String namespaceUri, String localName,
                           String qualifiedName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {
    if (someConditionOrOther) {
        throw new MySAXTerminatorException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: There any other way? not use exception.

Comment: Why would you not want to?  That's what exceptions are designed for.

Comment: fwiw, that isn't what exceptions are designed for. Terminating a parse like this is not an error condition.

It is however the only way to do this afaict :-(

Comment: In fact, it should be [SAXParseException](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html) so you can populate a Locator, and get a callback on the ErrorHandler (which is the right place to 'tidy up').

Comment: Here is good example - [Stop a SAX parser when you have enough data](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipsaxstop/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of a mechanism to abort SAX parsing other than the exception throwing technique [outlined by Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345293/how-to-stop-parsing-xml-document-with-sax-at-any-time/1345322#1345322). An alternative is to switch to using the [StAX parser](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html) (see [pull vs push](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbdw.html#bnbdy)).

Answer (score 2):

I use a boolean variable "`stopParse`" to consume the listeners since i don´t like to use `throw new SAXException()`;

```
private boolean stopParse;

article.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                if(stopParse) {
                  return; //if stopParse is true consume the listener.
                }
                setTitle(body);
            }
        });
```

#### Update:

@PanuHaaramo, supossing to have this .xml

```
<root>
        <article>
               <title>Jorgesys</title>
        </article>
        <article>
               <title>Android</title>
        </article>
        <article>
               <title>Java</title>
        </article>
</root>
```

the parser to get the "title" value using android SAX must be:

```
   import android.sax.Element;
   import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
   import android.sax.RootElement;
...
...
...
    RootElement root = new RootElement("root");
    Element article= root.getChild("article");
    article.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
                public void end(String body) {
                    if(stopParse) {
                      return; //if stopParse is true consume the listener.
                    }
                    setTitle(body);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is this for Android? I can only find `android.sax.EndTextElementListener`. Also what is `article` here?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not developing for Android but clears it up! I guess this is then not doable in regular Java (which I'm using).