# Limit XML SAXParser to certain number or item

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I am parsing an rss XML news feed for an Android app.  I am using `SAXParser` and all is working as it should but I would like to be able to limit the number of stories that I am retrieving and I cannot find a way to do so.  For instance, say there are 45 stories from one of the news feeds and I just want the newest 10. As it is now, I am just grabbing them all into an `ArrayList` and only displaying the ones I want, which most certainly is the most efficient way of doing this I am sure.

I can provide the parsing code if necessary.

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

Comment: When you are adding objects to arraylist simply check its size and don't add to it if it has 10 elements.

Comment: I thought about that but that would mean that the entire XML will still get parsed.  I would rather simply stop parsing once the `ArrayList` gets to the desired size.

Comment: You could just break out/return from the parsing operation after hitting the desired number of elements (or until there are no more to process, whichever comes first)?

Comment: How so @MH. ?  Will a simple `break` work if I add a counter to the `startElement()` method where I am adding objects to the list?

Comment: Sorry, that comment was a little inaccurate: a break or return won't work. You'll have to throw an exception, as suggested [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipsaxstop/). A quick search on SO yields the same answer. Not the prettiest, but functional, I suppose... Have a look at the [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345293/how-to-stop-parsing-xml-document-with-sax-at-any-time) for some concrete pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop a SAX parser from parsing any more input by having any of your callback methods (e.g. startElement) throw a SAXException.

You will need to make this exception recognizable (e.g. by using special message text, or by using a subclass of SAXException) so that when your original call of parse() comes back with an exception, you can distinguish it from other causes of parser failure.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: Not a simple one, I'm afraid. There's an example of the general technique at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8/net/sf/saxon/event/PIGrabber.java, but it's not using SAX interfaces directly, so the events and exceptions are slightly different. (This example is to read the xml-stylesheet processing instruction at the start of a file, and then abort the parse when the first element node is encountered.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a way to stop sax parser from parsing. However you can use `XMLPullParser` instead.

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(yourXML);

int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && list.size() <= MAX_SIZE) {

    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        //do something
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        //do something
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        //do something
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

You can find lots of examples by searching XMLPullParser tutorial.

**Note:** I think in case you have just 45 items parsing is very fast and you can let sax to continue parsing.

**Update:** I think it is what Michael says:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

   if(size == MAX_SIZE){
      throw new SAXException("end");
    }
    //...
 }
```

And when you are parsing:

```
try{
saxParser.parse(yourXML);
}catch(SAXException e){
  if(e.getMessage().equals("end"){
    // document has ended
  }
}
```

Comment: I just used 45 as an example.  What if there are hundreds?  It's not so fast anymore. I am aware of PullParser but need to learn more about SAX.